# How to convert a text file to an array in Visual Basic 2008 line by line?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, text-files

I am newer to Visual Basic and I am trying to get into file reading. From what I've found online I haven't found anything that wasn't entirely confusing to me.

I am trying to make a simple game to test some dialogue things and I want the options of what you can say to be predetermined. Right now I have a few sentences in arrays, but what I really want to do is just type everything into a text file with a different item on each line and then convert each line to a separate item of an array.

What I have right now is:

```
Dim convoStarters() As String = {"Hello", "Who are you?", "Who the hell are you?"}
```

What I want to do is take information from a text file organized like so:

```
Hello
Who are you?
Who the hell are you?
```

and put each line into an array that looks exactly like the one I have above (except of course, I'd add more things to the text file).

Thank you for helping a new guy out, have a nice day.

Comment: I imagine you meant VB.NET and not VBA (both for visual-studio tag and game development purpose). Could you please specify (and/or correct the tag)?

Comment: I don't have any code, because like I specified I don't know how. And it is VBA.

Comment: can't edit previous so I'll say it here: yeah I meant VB.Net sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant VB.NET and not VBA (both for the tag to Visual Studio and for the purpose of development a game), you can use a `StreamReader` to read the file line by line and adding the elements to the string then:

**VB.NET SOLUTION**

Note: if you didn't do yet, to interact with any file (input or output) you need to import the IO of the system, which means state this on top of your code:

```
Imports System.IO
```

...then...

**GLOBAL VARIABLES (on top of the module, out of any sub/function)**

```
Dim myStringElements As Integer
Dim convoStarters() As String
```

**SUB CODE**
    Public Sub yourSub()
    myStringElements = 0
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path) 'this object will read the text file

```
Do While sr.Peek() >= 0 'this will loop through the lines until the end
    AddElementToStringArray(sr.ReadLine()) 'this will add the single line to the string array
Loop
sr.Close()
End Sub
```

**PUBLIC FUNCTION BODY (another sub that makes the adding job)**

```
Public Sub AddElementToStringArray(ByVal stringToAdd As String)
    ReDim Preserve convoStarters(myStringElements)
    convoStarters(myStringElements) = stringToAdd
    myStringElements += 1
End Sub
```

**VBA SOLUTION**

But if as of your comment you rather meant VBA, then the logic is the same but the syntax is slightly different:

**GLOBAL VARIABLES**

```
Dim myStringElements As Integer
Dim convoStarters() As String
```

**SUB CODE**

```
    myStringElements = 0
    Open "C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\Test.txt" For Input As #1

    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        AddElementToStringArray (DataLine) 'this will add the single line to the string array
    Wend
```

**PUBLIC FUNCTION BODY**

```
Public Sub AddElementToStringArray(ByVal stringToAdd As String)
    ReDim Preserve convoStarters(myStringElements)
    convoStarters(myStringElements) = stringToAdd
    myStringElements += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Eh sorry I'm kinda just new to the whole thing and maybe i did mean VBA? I'm not sure now haha with the .Net code I get "StreamReader is nto defined" and with the VBA code I get "Open is not declared" as the first error.

Comment: ...do you actually have a project or this was just a philosophical idea for when you will start? :/

Comment: Ok, so... are you writing code into an Excel VBA editor, or have you created a VB project with Visual Studio? If the first case, then you need the VBA copy; if the second, then you need the first set.

Comment: Yes I did indeed problem solve and figured out I needed to import. Sorry about that. Just a super confused newbie and you helped a ton! Thank you!

Comment: Accept the answerif it worked, it will mean to other users with your same problem that this is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to find out, how many elements are necessary for your array.

By counting the numbers of '","' + 1 you have the numbers of elements existing in your string.

Please have a look in string methods like instr(), mid(), left(), rtrim(), ltrim() ..

With the number of elements you found you can REDIM array, or REDIM PRESERVER array

for your example REDIM strArr(nrElements)  or if you need to add some elements without
loosing content use REDIM PRESERVE strArr(nrElements).

Then you can fill it up:
for x = LBound(strArr,1) to Ubound(strArr,1)
       strArr(x) = Stringpart(x)
next x

Always open your "direct window" in VBA Editor under menu "view" and use debupg.print strArr(x)